# Delete from or Insert into database using Java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, sql, user-interface, insert

My code can execute select statements just fine, but for some reason I can't get the insert and delete segments to work. I believe they should be the same right? I just don't know what's wrong with my code right here.

```
    else if (e.getSource() == executeButton) {
        //Create a statement
        if (enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("select")){
            try{
                String commandString = enterSQLText.getText();
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                //Execute a statement
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(commandString);
                //Process query results
                ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

                for(int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++){
                  executionResultText.append(metaData.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                  System.out.printf("%20s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
                }
                executionResultText.append("\n");
                System.out.println();

                while (resultSet.next()){
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++){
                        executionResultText.append(resultSet.getObject(i).toString() + "\t");
                        System.out.printf("%20s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));
                    }
                    executionResultText.append("\n");
                    System.out.println();
                 }
                 System.out.println("Execute Button Works!");
              }
              catch (Exception h){
                h.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        else if (enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("delete") || enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
            try {
                String commandString = enterSQLText.getText();
                Statement statement = conn.prepareStatement(commandString);
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeUpdate(commandString);
            }
            catch (Exception l){
                l.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            executionResultText.setText("Sorry, that is not a valid command");
            System.out.println("Not a vilid command.");
        }
    }
```

Within the else if statement is where I'm having the problem. It usually just throws a stack trace error if I try to run an insert or delete statement. Can someone please help?

EDIT:

To get the code to execute, I had to change the else if segment to the following:

```
else if (enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("delete") || enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
                try {
                    String commandString = enterSQLText.getText();
                    Statement statement = conn.prepareStatement(commandString);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    int resultSet = statement.executeUpdate(commandString);
                }
                catch (Exception l){
                    l.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

When I try to execute an insert or delete command, I get a stack trace like this one:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Mark Renshaw' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at ConnectToDB.actionPerformed(ConnectToDB.java:203)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

No matter what I do to that segment, it either prevents me from being able to connect to the database, or throws an error.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant stack trace?

Comment: Consider adding your stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Duplicate key is pretty clear. There's another row in your table with the same primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Mark Renshaw' for key 'PRIMARY'

Is quite obvious. You are trying to insert a duplicate entry for a primary key. Primary Keys are unique and you cannot use the same key twice.

You probably don't want your name column to be a primary key. Use a autogenerated ID column for that.

Otherwise delete the column containing "Mark Renshaw" and run your code again. However it will only work once as you run into a conflict when running it twice with the same name.

Comment: In the end I was over thinking it. Below is the working segment for DELETE and INSERT.

    else if (enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("delete") || enterSQLText.getText().toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
        try {
         String commandString = enterSQLText.getText();
         conn.prepareStatement(commandString).executeUpdate(commandString);
        }
        catch (Exception l){
         l.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

Thanks for the help!